# I am facing problem in my archive page , it is partially working

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-post-type-archives

I am using wordpress 5.1 and I am creating a blogging website.  I am having an issue in my blog posts: when I click the permalink(link) of category it is showing the output but when I click the author it is showing "page not found error.  I have checked all the code of my team file but I am seeing nothing wrong.

[image]

[image]

Comment: haha.  Fictional University for the win!  Show your code so I can help.